# How can I revert add/remove class on click?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I'm trying to make an accordion div with an arrow up/down symbol that changes on click.  When I drop it down the arrow changes from down to up, but not reverse...

here's the code:

```
accordion: function() {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

        //expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

        if($('.accordion-content').is(":visible")){
            //console.log('visible');
            $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-down').addClass('icon-arrow-up');
        } else {
            //console.log('invisible');
            $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
        }

        //hide the other panels
        $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
},
```

Comment: provide html or make a Demo but I think you should reverse $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');  and  $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

Comment: as an aside: I would advise removing the line that closes the other accordions, users often want to compare the contents of two accordions side by side

Comment: also, refactoring your code to use classes directly on the elements that are being targeted rather than using DOM traversal will quite often help resolve errors like this, as well as making the code more maintainable and easier to understand and re-use

Answer (score 1):

You will have problems checking its visibility with JQuery Slide. Unlike .show() and .hide(), slide doesn't immediately change an element's visibility. So, you run the function .slideToggle(), and WHILE the element is still sliding (aka, still visible), you're asking if it's visible. So, you always get true, therefore leaves the arrow down.

Either add a class and check it, as such:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle('fast').toggleClass('im-open-yo');
...
if($('.accordion-content').hasClass("im-open-yo"){
...
$('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast').removeClass('im-open-yo');
```

OR run your queries on the function complete callback, because by then the visibility of the element will have changed:

```
 $(this).next().slideToggle('fast',function(){
 if(){...} 
});
```

Also, one thing to look out for,

```
if($('.accordion-content').is(":visible"))
```

will be checking for ANY accordion-content to be visible. So, if the  that has the arrow classes is for the entire accordion, great. If, however, the arrow is available for any of the accordion-toggles, you'll need to set this up differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with you

```
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
            var thisIt = $(this);
            //hide the other panels and return arrows to up
            $('.accordion-content').not(thisIt.next('.accordion-content')).slideUp('fast',function(){
              $(this).closest('.accordion-toggle').find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
            });
            //expand or collapse this panel
            thisIt.next('.accordion-content').slideToggle('fast' , function(){
               $(this).closest('.accordion-toggle').find('span').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up');
            });
        });
```

may help